# Content Types Template problem with lookup column in template

Tags: document-library, content-type, lookup-column

I have a content type. When I want to create a new document from that content type the properties (Columns) for that content type also open in my document.

The problem is that there is one lookup column which only shows the first 30 rows. But I need them all.

Any idea where I can set up that all rows are displayed in my drop down menu?

Answer (score -1):

Fixed with editing item limit in datasource list.